# How I can install a Homebrew recipe maintained in a separate git repository outside of /usr/local/Library/Formula?

Tags: git, homebrew, macos

I'm writing a quick [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) formula for my own private purposes (it's unlikely to be shared). I'd like to install it , but would prefer not to maintain my own local fork of Homebrew, but instead outside `/usr/local/Library/Formula` (it happens to be within an existing private git repository I have, but I think that's incidental to the question).

I've tried:

- `brew install ./my-formula.rb`
- `brew install file:///Users/myusername/mygitrepository/my-formula.rb`.

Neither seems to work. Instead I see:

`Error: No available formula for my-formula
==> Searching formulae...
==> Searching taps...`

How can I install this formula?

*Note*: Installing the formula using git repository syntax is unlikely to be what I need - I'm looking to install the formula *during its development*, in other words before I commit to my git repo.

I am using Homebrew 0.9.5.

Comment: Have you tried using `brew install -f my-formula.rb`?

Comment: Harry, unfortunately that fails with `Error: No available formula with the name "my-formula"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ln -s /Users/myusername/mygitrepository/my-formula.rb /usr/local/Library/Formula/
brew install my-formula
```

Both `brew doctor` and `brew update` shouldn't mind, at least not until a `my-formula` formula is added into the official brew repository!

Comment: This works, thanks. It's not ideal since it still involves touching `/usr/local/Library/Formula`, and I'd like to keep the formula entirely separate from homebrew's own repo, but it does work. Thanks!